# Hyper Terminal commands not working on WSL 2

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyperterminal

- have configured it properly otherwise adding in wsl.exe to the path linking it. I am now trying to add in plugins to my Hyper, but I keep on getting this error whenever I type in a Hyper command. I have tried reinstalling hyper a few times every time doing nothing.

  hyper -v

  Disabling Chromium GPU blacklist
  running in prod mode
  electron will open file://C:\Users\joeyg\AppData\Local\hyper\app-3.0.2\resources\app.asar\index.html
  Error while loading dev tools extensions Error: Cannot create process, error code: 267

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed ut by adding this into your zshrc or bashrc file.

```
alias hyper="cmd.exe /c hyper"
```

This allows it to work. However, it isn't going to work because of the path issue. None of the plugins work at though :(. It is super sad how they don't work. Additionally, it seems to be abandoned when it comes to command, and simply says it isn't supported. I really hate it when you open a new tab and it isn't on the same path.

Answer (score 5):

Use the shell Args like this

```sh
shell: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe',
shellArgs: ['~'],
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with WSL.

This isn't the solution but you could temporarily change your shell in the config-file.

```
shell: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe'
```

And then execute all your hyper commands.